# Spark JSON read failing

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

1:)I have to build a code that would read a json file in spark.
I am using **spark.read.json("sample.json")** for it.
But even for simple json file like the following

```
{
   {"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25"}
   {"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28"}
   {"id" : "1203", "name" : "amith", "age" : "39"}
   {"id" : "1204", "name" : "javed", "age" : "23"}
   {"id" : "1205", "name" : "prudvi", "age" : "23"}
}
```

I am getting wrong results

```
+---------------+----+----+-------+
|_corrupt_record| age|  id|   name|
+---------------+----+----+-------+
|              {|null|null|   null|
|           null|  25|1201| satish|
|           null|  28|1202|krishna|
|           null|  39|1203|  amith|
|           null|  23|1204|  javed|
|           null|  23|1205| prudvi|
|              }|null|null|   null|
+---------------+----+----+-------+
```

I found the above example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spark_sql/spark_sql_json_datasets.htm)

2:)Moreover, I don't know how to handle malformed json files like the following

```
{
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

I am finding it very difficult to work with these kinds of files.
Is there any coherent way to deal with json files in Java/Scala apart from spark

Please help

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON file should look like this:

```
{"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25"}
{"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28"}
{"id" : "1203", "name" : "amith", "age" : "39"}
{"id" : "1204", "name" : "javed", "age" : "23"}
{"id" : "1205", "name" : "prudvi", "age" : "23"}
```

And the code would be:

```
%spark.pyspark

# sqlContext
sq = sqlc

# setup input
file_json = "hdfs://mycluster/user/test/test.json"

df = sqlc.read.json(file_json)
df.registerTempTable("myfile")

df2 = sqlc.sql("SELECT * FROM myfile")

df2.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+-------+
|age|  id|   name|
+---+----+-------+
| 25|1201| satish|
| 28|1202|krishna|
| 39|1203|  amith|
| 23|1204|  javed|
| 23|1205| prudvi|
+---+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For Reading the Json Data that has format like below is very simple.
[
   {
     "code": "AAA",
    "lat": "-17.3595",
    "lon": "-145.494",
    "name": "Anaa Airport",
    "city": "Anaa",
    "state": "Tuamotu-Gambier",
    "country": "French Polynesia",
    "woeid": "12512819",
    "tz": "Pacific/Midway",
    "phone": "",
    "type": "Airports",
    "email": "",
    "url": "",
    "runway_length": "4921",
    "elev": "7",
    "icao": "NTGA",
    "direct_flights": "2",
    "carriers": "1"
  },

In Spark, using scala , you can get data as:

```
object Airport_Data {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Airport_Analysis").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val Sql_Context = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import Sql_Context.implicits._
println("SQL Context and SPARK Context has been initialized")

def data_show() = {
val airport_df = Sql_Context.read.option("multiLine", true).option("mode", 
"PERMISSIVE").json("C://Users//133288//Desktop//Flight//airports.json")
airport_df.show()
println("***************************")

// Print the Schema in tree format
println("************Print the Schema in tree format***************")
airport_df.printSchema()

// Select only the "Specific" Column
println("************Select only the 'Specific' Column***************")
airport_df.select("name").show()


// select everybody, but increment the "runway_length" by 2
println("************select everybody, but increment the 'runway_length' by 
2***************")
airport_df.select($"name", $"runway_length" + 200).show()

// select airports whose runway_lenth is greater than 4000
println("*************Select Airport with runway length Greater than 
5000************")
airport_df.filter($"runway_length" > 
5000).write.parquet("C://Users//133288//Desktop//Flight//Airport_lenth_5000.parquet")
airport_df.filter($"runway_length" > 
5000).write.csv("C://Users//133288//Desktop//Flight//Airport_lenth_5000")

}
```